# django-modeltranslation not removing database fields when language is removed

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

I am using django-modeltranslation to implement localization in my project.

I have a model attribute *name* which support localization. Previously two languages were enabled English and German and the sync_translation_fields command created *name_en* and *name_de* in database. But when I removed German and added French the command only creates *name_fr* and *name_de* still remains there.

Comment: I don't think `sync_translation_fields` is supposed to remove the old fields. From looking at the docs, it seems like you should do the standard `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` every time you change the languages in `settings.LANGUAGES` or `settings.MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES`